# How to initialize Spring application when Redis is not available?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

I need my Spring boot application to continue initializing whether the configured Redis server dependency is available or not.

On the other hand, this does not apply to the database, as I want to fail fast if DB is not available or has other initialization issues.

Simplest solution I found so far is the configuration option `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true`, but this will also ignore database initialization errors, which is obviously not what I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JPA for DB mapping then it possible to do a lazy initialization of your Repository classes

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(bootstrapMode=BootstrapMode.LAZY)
```

In order to intialize Redis connection conditionally you can create a new class

```
@Configuration
@Profile("redisDB)
public class RedisDBConfiguration{
....
}
```

**OR** you can enable and disable Redis Repositories in properties based on different spring profiles

application.yml

```
spring:
  data:
    redis:
      repositories:
        enabled: false
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it doesn't really solve my problem. I need to use a single profile, which would load Postgres repositories eagerly at initialization (and fail if not connection fails) but skip Redis if connection fails and continue initializing.
I already have the redis repositories disabled, as I only need the PUB/SUB feature and I use no repositories or cache.